# kendoTextBox inside Kendo-grid-column Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, grid

I am trying to display kendoTextBox/kendoTextArea in the KendoGrid.
Below is the markup -

```
 <kendo-grid [data]="data">

    <kendo-grid-column field="test" title="test" width="150">
      <textarea kendoTextArea></textarea>

        </kendo-grid-column>

  </kendo-grid>
```

But the textbox isnt visible. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kendo-grid-column use ng-template. Inside ng-template, can declare textbox

```
<kendo-grid [data]="data">
    <kendo-grid-column title="Input Box" [width]="150">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <textarea kendoTextArea></textarea>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are looking to add a kendo textarea dynamically please refer: http://www.aisoftwarellc.com/blog/post/how-to-display-text-area-editor-in-kendo-grid/2042

To make life easy:

```
    function textAreaEditor(container, options) {
       $('<textarea class="k-textbox" name="' + options.field + '" 
       style="width:100%;height:100%;" />').appendTo(container);
      }

     //use above function in grid configuration
     columns: [
      { field: "description", width: "300px", editor: textAreaEditor }
      ]
```